# What's the difference between 'selected' and 'defaultSelected' when constructing an HTMLOptionElement?

Tags: javascript

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option):

> defaultSelected - Optional
> A Boolean that sets the selected attribute
> value, i.e. so that this  will be the default value selected
> in the  element when the page is first loaded. If this is not
> specified, a default value of false is used. Note that a value of true
> does not set the option to selected if it is not already selected.
>
> selected - Optional
> A Boolean that sets the option's selected state;
> the default is false (not selected). If omitted, even if the
> defaultSelected argument is true, the option is not selected.

This is very unclear to me. `defaultSelected` determines if "this will be the default value selected", but one sentence later it says "a value of true does not set the option to selected if it is not already selected". So... it doesn't set it to be selected? It only sets it to selected if it's already selected?

`selected` claims also to set the selected state. If it's omitted, regardless of `defaultSelected`, the option is not selected. So... `defaultSelected` does nothing?

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `defaultSelected` property represents the initial (default) selection state of an element and corresponds to the *selected* HTML attribute. The `selected` property represents the current selection state and that is what a user actually sees selected in the browser.

When a user selects an option, only the `selected` property is changed, while the attribute and the `defaultSelected` property stay the same (they can still be changed programmatically though). You can use this, for instance, to reset some settings to defaults.

So I'd say you would generally use either

```
 new Option(text, value, true, true)
```

or

```
new Option(text, value, false, false)
```

Setting different values for the 3rd and the 4th parameters means you create an option which is the default value, but is not currently selected, or vice versa.

I find the docs rather confusing as well, but I guess that

> defaultSelected - <...> Note that a value of true does not set the option to selected if it is not already selected

means just that - if you set the `defaultSelected` to true, it does not mean that the option will actually be selected, it just sets the option as the default selected value. For it to be selected you have to set the `selected` property as well.

Also, when you add the `selected` attribute in HTML, the corresponding DOM element gets both `defaultSelected` and `selected` properties set to *true*, so both initial and current selected values are the same.

Here is a useful answer for a related question about attributes and properties of DOM elements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6004028/1630480

Answer (score 0):

*seems to me* that defaultSelected = true is meant to be a decision on behalf of the user. I noticed that the 'option' having true setting for defaultSelected has the "selected" html attribute in the rendered html, yet its not the selected item in the list. beats me why but i understand the intention of it somewhat.